# Rate changes over time

Tags: regression, time-series

I need two sets of data collected over 3 years. The first data has 12 waves where each wave represents a quarter. The other has 24 waves where each wave include some part of the previous wave (e.g. 1st wave 1/1/07-4/30/07; 2nd wave 3/1/07-6/30/07 ...)

The variables measured were rates (specific lab tests taken from certain patient populations). The data were collected to examine the effect of new reporting system. So finding whether there is a significant increase of test rates over time or not is my interests. I don't have 0 rates in the data.

- Would negative binomial regression appropriate for this type of
  analysis?
- Or if I take only the first and last waves to compare the differences
  in rates, what would be the best way?